# How to be a freelance creative writer?

Tags: freelance-websites, marketing

I have done a small amount of research on the internet about freelance writing. Almost all of the articles I have read relate to freelancers that write articles about a specific topic or a range of topics that the writer has a specialty in. My passion and specialty is in creative writing and poetry. I have just now started my blog, but have some writing that has just been sitting around that has not been posted too. How do creative writers get into freelancing? Is there somewhere else I should be looking? I see some post for ghost writers and that sort of thing, but is there a different term that I should be using? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have hired writers from many places. I look for writers on Craigslist, Facebook groups and freelancer websites. Employers like me are looking for quality and turn around.

I've hired freelancers for small projects and have many times ran into issues with reliability. My agency has hard deadlines for projects and I need the content to get started right away on some aspects of the marketing campaign my agency is handling for my clients.

With creative writing are you looking to create sales pages and web copy? There are places like Fiverr you could also get started out and make a name for yourself if you do a great job.

What is your blog?

Answer (score 1):

Creative writing and poetry are typically not the kinds of writing that people looking for "freelance writers" want. If you want to earn income from that kind of writing, you need to write the story/novel/poem(s) first and then look for an agent or publisher, or self-publish through Amazon or other outlets.

You can also make some decent money doing business writing - writing copy for advertisements, brochures, direct mail pieces, etc. In order to make a name for yourself in this category, you need to meet your deadlines and have impeccable spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I think Joe just asked a great question: what is your blog?

You should start blogging on some sites like medium.com or on relevant sites that are related to the topics you enjoy. Create a blog today if you don't have one or get a website that you can display some of your work and even testimonials from people you have written for in the past.

There are sites like freelancer.com and more that have contract/job postings and you can set your rates on these websites. However, these websites have many users and it can be easy to get drowned out.

In the end, people need to know you are out there and need to be able to read samples of your work to get an idea. Use social media to your advantage.

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

Becoming a successful ghostwriter requires a unique blend of writing skill, professionalism, and adaptability. Firstly, hone your writing abilities across different genres and styles to cater to diverse client needs. Develop a strong portfolio showcasing your versatility and ability to capture various voices.

Establishing a solid network is crucial; connect with publishers, literary agents, and other writers to increase your visibility. Building a reputation as a reliable professional is essential for long-term success. Confidentiality is paramount in ghostwriting, so emphasize your discretion and ability to handle sensitive information.

Understanding your clients' needs is key. Be a good listener, ask insightful questions, and immerse yourself in their vision. Your adaptability is your greatest asset; be ready to work on projects ranging from memoirs and self-help books to business manuals.

Develop excellent communication skills to translate clients' ideas into compelling narratives. Meeting deadlines is non-negotiable, so manage your time efficiently and deliver high-quality work consistently.

Continuous learning is vital in a dynamic writing landscape. Stay updated on industry trends, hone your research skills, and be open to feedback. Embrace technology to streamline your writing process.

Lastly, market yourself effectively. Create a professional website, leverage social media, and seek testimonials from satisfied clients. A successful ghostwriter is not just a goldsmith but also a savvy entrepreneur, building a brand that reflects reliability, creativity, and adaptability

Comment: Nobody said anything about ghostwriting.  This is just nonsense spouted by some chatbot.