# How to succeed as a freelance writer?

Tags: freelance-websites, working-from-home, resume, writing

I want to be a freelance writer, I've done some research on it and I will be signing up for online classes to learn more about the subject. Is there anybody on here who has succeeded as a freelance writer and could provide tips on the road ahead?

Comment: You may find some answers in quite a few similar, if not identical, topics on this site: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=freelance+writer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to be a freelance creative writer?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/how-to-be-a-freelance-creative-writer)

Comment: Hi Aaron, there's a wealth of information on the Internet about how to succeed as a freelance writer. Take a look at that information, and come back with more specific questions. Our site works best when there is a specific problem to be solved. See [ask] for details. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I tried to be a writer. I got freelancing tasks to rewrite some texts. In the end, it turned out to be a lot of work for the minimum rate.

After I was asked to make a master paper for some small money, I stopped being a writer.

I turned to programming and my perspective on the freelancing turned 180 degrees. At that time I also read a lot of stories of other writers and watched their profiles on freelancer sites, and realized that 99% of them are not earning much.

Also if you want to do anything in English, I have to say that native and Philipino writers will win over you (in case you are not native like myself).

Comment: What kind of topics were you writing about?

Comment: Had to think about this answer, could not believe I forgot it :). I am still not sure, but I remember we had a system with a list of essays that we could pick and write. So I picked those that are IT related and wrote about them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a some experience in the matter but I think my biggest mistake was confusing a desire to be a freelance writer, with the desire of working from home. I get the same perks now as a programmer and the rates are good.

The rates seem really low for freelance writers in my opinion, especially on the freelance job websites. If you establish a good relationship with clients and always deliver good quality work on time, they will definitely prefer working with you, even if it means paying a higher rate but it's very hard to build those relationships online.

I think a good approach is getting involved in some indie projects like for games and short films.  Writing is something often over-looked which explains why a lot of indie projects lack good dialog, narratives and publicity.

Bottom line, think outside the box, don't do what everyone else is doing and build relationships with clients that will keep them coming back for more even if it means doing some pro bono work here and there

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on whether or not you're already a writer and entering freelancing or beginning your writing career as a freelancer.  Either way, freelance writing is like many other kinds of freelancing.  You need to be resourceful and be a go-getter.  Don't wait for work to come to you.  If you're already a writer then you already know the ins and outs of making writing a success.  In freelancing you will be your own boss and will have to do whatever your boss would do.  Good luck.